# Searching id in an array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I need to search an array and print the matched value.
For which my array would be:

```
$my_values = array(
'' => '---',
'12' => 'Bungalows',
'43' => 'Character property',
'277' => 'Guest house',
'49' => 'Flat share'
);
```

This is my array and I need to display the name if it matches the id. Suppose, if the id is 12 the Bungalows needs to be displayed.
I know this:

```
$key = array_search('Bungalows', $my_values);
```

This code gives me 12 but I need to output 'Bungalows' instead of 12. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean by `This code gives me 12 but I need exact opposite.` ?

Comment: I want to search for '12' not 'bungalows'

Comment: You found 12 which has Bungalows linked to it within the array. All you need to do is `$my_values[$key]` and you'll get Bungalows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the key exists then print the value if True,

```
$key = "12";   
if (array_key_exists ( $key, $my_values) )  
{
     echo $my_values[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for `12` try this:

```
$search = 12;

if (isset($my_values[$search])) {
  echo $my_values[$search]; // Should output Bungalows
}
else {
  echo 'Not found!';
}
```

If you are searching for `Bungalows` try this:

```
$search = 'Bungalows';

$key = array_search($search, $my_values);

echo $my_values[$key]; // Should output Bungalows
```

Answer (score 0):

So if the value is "Bungalows" it should print "Bungalows", if its "Guest house" it should print "Guest house", but if its "My house" it shouldn't print anything?

This should work:

```
$my_values = array(
'' => '---',
'12' => 'Bungalows',
'43' => 'Character property',
'277' => 'Guest house',
'49' => 'Flat share'
);

$search = 'Bungalows';

echo in_array($search, $my_values) ? $search : null;
```

Comment: Search for '12' and echo Bungalows

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'foo'   => 'bar',
    1       => 'this',
    'that'  => 42
);

echo $array[ array_search('that', $array) ]; //42
```

Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

`$my_values[$id]` should do the trick